# For any rows with a NaN in a Pandas DataFrame, shift by 1

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn

df = DataFrame(randn(5, 3), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'], columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df2 = df.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])
df2['one']['i'] = 5
```

This is my output

```
        one       two     three
a -1.132283 -1.204504 -0.763302
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c  1.778895 -1.931615 -0.040319
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e  0.612546 -0.846982  0.524779
f -0.527883  0.342746 -0.010093
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h -0.636055 -0.909910  0.642658
i  5.000000       NaN       NaN
```

What I'm trying to figure out is for the columns that have a NaN in the last row (this being row i, I would like to shift those columns by 1.)

Right now, I am doing `df2['two'].shift(1)` and `df2['three'].shift(1)`, but is there a recommended way of coding this that I'm missing?

So I get `df2[-1:]` as the last index ... but I'm slightly stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a way to do this with less duplication, but the following should work, anyway.  First, find out which columns we need to shift, and then replace those columns by the shifted versions.

```
to_shift = pd.isnull(df2.iloc[-1])
df2.loc[:,to_shift] = df2.loc[:,to_shift].shift(1)
```

---

Get the last row:

```
>>> df2.iloc[-1]
one       5
two     NaN
three   NaN
Name: i, dtype: float64
```

See where there's missing data:

```
>>> pd.isnull(df2.iloc[-1])
one      False
two       True
three     True
Name: i, dtype: bool
>>> to_shift = pd.isnull(df2.iloc[-1])
```

Select that portion of the frame:

```
>>> df2.loc[:, to_shift]
        two     three
a -0.447225  0.240786
b       NaN       NaN
c  1.736224  0.191835
d       NaN       NaN
e -0.310505  2.121659
f  2.542979 -0.772117
g       NaN       NaN
h -0.350395  0.825386
i       NaN       NaN
```

Shift it:

```
>>> df2.loc[:, to_shift].shift(1)
        two     three
a       NaN       NaN
b -0.447225  0.240786
c       NaN       NaN
d  1.736224  0.191835
e       NaN       NaN
f -0.310505  2.121659
g  2.542979 -0.772117
h       NaN       NaN
i -0.350395  0.825386
```

And fill the frame with the shifted data:

```
>>> df2.loc[:, to_shift] = df2.loc[:, to_shift].shift(1)
>>> df2
        one       two     three
a -0.691010       NaN       NaN
b       NaN -0.447225  0.240786
c  0.570639       NaN       NaN
d       NaN  1.736224  0.191835
e  2.509598       NaN       NaN
f -2.053269 -0.310505  2.121659
g       NaN  2.542979 -0.772117
h  1.812492       NaN       NaN
i  5.000000 -0.350395  0.825386
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked great for me and was simple enough.